# How to view network shares in a consitant way?

Tags: networking, file-sharing, shared-folders

How do I make ubuntu show network shares the same in every application? I cannot access network shares from certain applications at all. If it isn't possible to make a consistent interface, is there at least a way of accessing network shares from applications that do not display them in the expected place?

nautilus shows my network shares as expected

[image: nautilus shows my network shares as expected]

gedit shows network shares in a different place

[image: gedit shows network shares in a different place]

virtualbox does not show network shares at all

[image: virtualbox does not show network shares at all]

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the App, maybe theres a reason for that, depends on which protocol are you sharing with (smb, ssh, etc), the latency that the app expect, maybe a lot of low level things that app dont support

Comment: virtualbox is able to use ISOs on network drivers on Windows without issue. Unless ubuntu is much slower than Windows I don't think it's a technical issue.

Comment: MS Windows is SMB-only Networking protocol, on Linux you have all existing protocols. Plus SMB is a weirdo protocol on technical part. Its a tipical case of Missing Feature of the App, the OS support all of them.

Comment: if I mount the share using fstab virtualbox can use it. why is using nautilus to mount the share so much slower than fstab?

Comment: Nautilus---> GVFS daemon, FStab ---> lower level  (i think this is going OT )

Comment: ok last comment. Guess I'll file a bug with GVFS daemon